# Sitecore fields items displayed twice in an content item created

Tags: sitecore

[image]

Please see the above image. I am seeing the title field in an content item created. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have enabled translation mode in Sitecore.

You can disable it from the Ribbon -> Versions -> Translate.

[image]